# Enable Apache SSL in Docker for local development

Tags: php, apache, ssl, docker, https

I'm dockerizing our current old app. We use several services but the one I have issues on is the php, apache, and specifically the https for apache. I am using "php:5.6.30-apache" image, so I have php and apache pre-installed.

Now I changed the "000-default.conf" with this content:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@admin.io
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/app/htdocsAdmin
    ServerName admin.local.app.io
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/app.admin.access.log "trueip_combined"
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/app.admin.error.log
    <Directory /var/www/html/app/htdocsAdmin>
        AllowOverride Options FileInfo AuthConfig
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This is my docker file:

```
FROM php:5.6.30-apache

MAINTAINER Tzook Bar Noy

ADD default /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf


RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y apt-utils \
  && apt-get install -y php5-dev php5-memcached \
  && apt-get install -y memcached



RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-utils
RUN apt-get install -y libz-dev libmemcached-dev
RUN pecl install memcached-2.2.0
RUN echo extension=memcached.so >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/memcached.ini

RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN a2enmod ssl


EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
```

*Don't mind the memcached stuff, just see that I enable "ssl" and expose ports 80,443*

This is being ran with docker-compose:

```
php:
build:
  context: ./php
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
ports:
  - "80:80"
  - "443:443"
volumes:
  - ./../../:/var/www/html
networks:
  - appnet
tty: true
```

but after all of that, I still get this from chrome:

```
"ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR"
```

As requested in comments my "docker ps" response:
[image]

Comment: Two things: you repeating the same command twice in your dockerfile; and you need to show the `docker run` command you used.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid which command?? and I run this with docker-compose, just pasted the relevant part of it here above.

Comment: After you run `docker-compose up -d` what is the output of `docker ps` and the log file for your apache container?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid attached my "docker ps" and nothing on the docker logs...

Comment: How did you configure SSL without uploading any certificates to your server?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid am I that stupid, that I have to add those, even if I don't really care about it, and its only for local use?

Comment: Yes unfortunately. You can use a self-signed certificate; or use truecrypt to get a free one. Otherwise, stick to http and port 80.

Comment: thanks @BurhanKhalid can you post any guide for self signed certificate, so at least I can make this post useful and thank you for the help

Answer (score 34):

Besides enabling ssl and exposing port 443, you need to create a (self-signed) certificate + private key and make sure Apache has access to those.

I recommend using openSSL to create a self-signed certificate:

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -days 3650 -nodes -x509 -subj \
    "/C=../ST=...../L=..../O=..../CN=..." \
    -keyout ./ssl.key -out ./ssl.crt
```

Instead of the dots (...) fill in your 2-letter country code (/C), the name of your state or province (/ST), the name of your locality (/L), the name of your organization (/O) and your server FQDN (/CN)

Then add the following lines to your docker file:

```
COPY ./path/to/ssl.crt /etc/apache2/ssl/ssl.crt
COPY ./path/to/ssl.key /etc/apache2/ssl/ssl.key
RUN mkdir -p /var/run/apache2/
```

I'm not sure the last line is really necessary, but in my docker container the folder didn't exist yet causing Apache to fail on startup.

Finally in your 000-default.conf file you need to add something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ssl.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ssl.key
  ....
</VirtualHost>
```

Note that when you use self-signed certificates most browsers will alert you that "Your connection is not secure" (Firefox) or "Invalid certificate" (Chrome). This is because there is no valid security chain to a trusted CA. Most browsers allow you to continue your request or add the site as an exception so the warning isn't displayed anymore.

Comment: In my case I used default-ssl.conf file for it, but forgot to enable the site (`a2ensite default-ssl`). This caused me the error `SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG` when accessing the site. I hope it helps who face the same issue. :)

Comment: what is `./path/to/ssl.crt ` ie what determines what the path is? Is that the DIR where docker is run from? My WORKDIR?

Comment: @James The assumption here is that Docker is running on the same device where you created the ssl files, so the COPY command is copying those files from the location where you created them to the Apache folder in the Docker container.

Answer (score 18):

Here's how I enabled Apache SSL in Docker for local development. This is with Docker running an Ubuntu image on macOS (though `mkcert` also works with Linux and Windows):

• In macOS, [install mkcert](https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert):

```
brew install mkcert
brew install nss # if you use Firefox
```

`mkcert` makes it easy to create and install SSL certificates for local development use.

• Create the SSL certificates:

```
mkcert mysite.localhost someothersite.localhost localhost 127.0.0.1 ::1
```

This will install them on macOS for you, but will also leave a copy of them in the current working directory:

```
mysite.localhost+4-key.pem
mysite.localhost+4.pem
```

• Make the two `.pem` files available to your Docker container. e.g.: move them with your container's config files and add the like of this:

```
- ./config/ssl:/etc/apache2/ssl/
```

• Open port `443` in the container's `docker-compose`:

```
- "443:443"
```

(And you should certainly `EXPOSE 443` in the image too, though for some reason it worked for me without doing so.) (Edit: [EXPOSE](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose) is purely documentation and performs no actions per the documentation)

• Enable SSL in Apache:

```
RUN ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/ssl.load  /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ssl.load
```

Though, technically, I did this from within my running container first, followed by an `apachectl restart`. Makes it easier to test things out and make sure everything worked *before* committing rebuilding the image.

• Configure your website(s) in Apache for them to use SSL by editing `mysite.localhost` and any other domain you want to use SSL with:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    …
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/etc/apache2/ssl/clickandspeak.localhost+4.pem"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/apache2/ssl/clickandspeak.localhost+4-key.pem"
    …
</VirtualHost>
```

…just duplicate your old config from `<VirtualHost *:80>`, change the port to `443`, and add the three lines above.

Rebuild the image and restart the container along the way as needed.

*…et voilà!*

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have to add following to enable the SSL :

```COPY ./config/ssl /etc/apache2/ssl/
COPY ./config/default-ssl.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf
RUN ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/ssl.load  /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ssl.load
RUN a2ensite default-ssl.conf
```

Answer (score 2):

The standard apache container has all the tools built in to create a self-signed certificate.

Add the following to your Dockerfile:

```
# Enable SSL
RUN set -eux; \
    apt-get update; \
    apt-get install ssl-cert; \
    a2enmod ssl; \
    a2ensite default-ssl
```