# run sveltekit dev with https

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

Is it possible, in development env, to run SvelteKit app with https?
I tried to run

```
npm run dev -- --https
```

and vite starts the server successfully:

```
VITE v3.0.2  ready in 359 ms

  ➜  Local:   https://localhost:5173/
  ➜  Network: [...]
```

but i can't connect to https://localhost:5173
chrome says: ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

I also tried to edit vite.config.js adding my certificate:

```
https: {
    key: readFileSync( `${__dirname}/../server/key.pem`),
    cert: readFileSync(`${__dirname}/../server/cert.pem`),
}
```

and i also tried to use mkcert() following this post:

[Vite https on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69417788/vite-https-on-localhost)

but it results in the same error

then I tried to use mkcert as plugin:

```
const config = {
    
    server: {       
        https: true
    },

    plugins: [sveltekit(), mkcert()],

};
```

this time, on first load, it seemed to work, but loading other pages with SvelteKit goto() led to the following different error:

```
TypeError [ERR_HTTP2_INVALID_CONNECTION_HEADERS]: HTTP/1 Connection specific headers are forbidden: "keep-alive"
```

Comment: "but it doesn't work" is not particularly specific.

Comment: I mean,  I got the same error: ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH and i can't connect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vite https on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69417788/vite-https-on-localhost)

Comment: No, it doesn't. I have updated my question to add more details.

Answer (score 14):

## Certificate part

Here I suggest you use mkcert for simplicity but you can also generate your certificate using `openssl`...

### install [mkcert](https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert)

```bash
brew install mkcert
```

### install a local certificate authority

```bash
> mkcert -install
Created a new local CA 
The local CA is now installed in the system trust store! ⚡️
The local CA is now installed in the Firefox trust store (requires browser restart)!
```

### create your certificate with `mkcert`

```bash
mkdir your_project/cert
cd your_project/cert
mkcert -key-file key.pem -cert-file cert.pem localhost
```

## Vite part

### update `vite.config.js` to include your cert files

```js
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import fs from 'fs';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [sveltekit()],
    server: {
        https: {
            key: fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/cert/key.pem`),
            cert: fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/cert/cert.pem`)
        }
    }
});
```

```js
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import fs from 'fs';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [sveltekit()],
    server: {
        https: {
            key: fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/../cert/key.pem`),
            cert: fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/../cert/cert.pem`)
        },
        proxy: {}
    }
});
```

then you should run `pnpm run dev` and see `Local: https://localhost:5173/` in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that add: proxy: {} to vite.config.js solved this problem, but I didn't fully understand why and the consequences of this choice

```
const config = {
    
    server: {       
        https: true,
        proxy: {} <==
    },

    plugins: [sveltekit(), mkcert()],

};
```

Comment: Probably because of this: https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-https 
"Note this downgrades to TLS only when the server.proxy option is also used."

Answer (score 0):

You could try [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/docs/http/#forward-to-https)

```
ngrok http https://localhost:8443
```