# Google Sign In Testing on localhost: issue with oAuth consent screen authorised domains

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-signin

I'm trying to sign in with Google on localhost without success.
I've set up the authorized javascript origins as expected (API&Services > Credentials)...

[image: authorised javascript origins]

...but after signing in, I still get this error:

[image: the error message after signing in]

You can see Google mentions that the `Authorised Javascript origins` are automatically added to the `OAuth consent screen` as `authorised domains`. So, I checked the `OAuth consent screen` and I don't see localhost:

[image: OAuth consent screen authorised domains]

... and I cannot add `localhost` in the `Authorized domains` list cause it requires a `top-level domain`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just switched to `https` using `mkcert` on my Svelte front and it worked.
See details here: [run sveltekit dev with https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73205096/run-sveltekit-dev-with-https/76525335#76525335)