# Sveltekit: Webapp can access camera but mobile version can not

Tags: javascript, camera, svelte, sveltekit, html5-qrcode

I'm working on a web app which will allow an user to read barcodes. I'm using Svelte and Sveltekit to do so. I have some code which runs well on my laptop. It asks for permission to access my camera and after I allow it I can see the camera and I'm able to scan codes.
To "activate" the camera I'm using a button at the moment. When the start button is clicked then the camera is visible, I can then click on the stop button and the camera will disappear.

As I just mentioned, this works well in my web browser (laptop) but when accessing the same app on my iPhone (haven't tried a different device yet) it does not behave the same. I see the Start button, but once I click it nothing seems to happen. I don't see any popup asking for permission to access the camera and although I can see the Stop button, clicking it has no effect whatsoever.

Here's my code:

```
<script>
    import {Html5Qrcode} from "html5-qrcode";
    import {onMount} from "svelte";

    let scanning = false

    let html5Qrcode

    onMount(init)

    function init() {
        html5Qrcode = new Html5Qrcode('reader')
    }

    async function start() {
        html5Qrcode.start(
            { facingMode: 'environment' },
            {
                fps: 10,
                qrbox: { width: 250, height: 250 },
            },
            onScanSuccess,
            onScanFailure
        )
        scanning = true
    }

    async function stop() {
        await html5Qrcode.stop()
        scanning = false
    }

    let result = "";
    function onScanSuccess(decodedText, decodedResult) {
        // alert(`Code matched = ${decodedText}`)
        console.log(decodedResult)
        result = decodedResult.decodedText;
        stop();
    }

    function onScanFailure(error) {
        // console.warn(`Code scan error = ${error}`)
        return;
    }
    
</script>

<div class="container mx-auto">
    <div style="width: 300px" id="reader"></div>
    {#if scanning}
        <button class="btn btn-success" on:click={stop}>stop</button>
    {:else}
        <button class="btn btn-warning" on:click={start}>start</button>
    {/if}
    <div id="result" class="text-3xl text-red-500">{ result }</div>
</div>
```

Any idea what's going on?

Thanks.

**Update**

When accessing the logs in dev tools from the attempt to Start the camera on my iPhone, I see the following error in the console:

> Unhandled Promise Rejection: Camera streaming not supported by the
> browsers

Don't understand why I'm getting this error. If I go to this codepen codepen.io/takatama/pen/dyZeWQJ in my iPhone (which uses the same library I'm using), it asks me for permission to use the camera and after being granted I can see it.

I believe the issue comes to the fact that I'm trying to access an http site from my phone so it does not allow it to have camera access.

Comment: Have you attached a debugger/dev tools to check console output for errors?

Comment: Do you use android 13? https://github.com/mebjas/html5-qrcode/issues/855

Comment: @H.B. I just did. This is what is the error in the console: **Unhandled Promise Rejection: Camera streaming not supported by the browsers** . Don't understand why I'm getting this error. If I go to this codepen https://codepen.io/takatama/pen/dyZeWQJ in my iPhone (which uses the same library I'm using), it asks me for permission to use the camera and after being granted I can see it

Comment: @kolja as I said in the question, I'm not using Android at the moment, only iOS

Comment: Please edit your question to include the error at the appropriate place. (I can't help you with this, don't have any apple devices.)

Comment: I found the solution!: the issue was exactly what i thought it was. I'm accessing an http site (localhost) from my phone so it deemed it insecure therefore it did not allow access to the camera. To get over this, simply set https for localhost, that way when the site is accessed from your phone via https it will ask you for permission to access the camera. Follow the steps in the response here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73205096/run-sveltekit-dev-with-https