# Vite self signed certificate error when calling local API

Tags: vuejs3, vite

I created a simple Vue3 app, and I'm trying to call another local API (on a different port) on my machine. To better replicate the production server environment, I'm making a call to a relative API path. That means I need to use a proxy on the vite server to forward the API request to the correct localhost port for my local development. I defined my vite proxy like this in my `vite.config.ts` file:

```js
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from "node:url";

import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import basicSsl from '@vitejs/plugin-basic-ssl'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    basicSsl(),
    vue()
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url)),
    },
  },
  server: {
    https: true,
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'https://localhost:44326', // The API is running locally via IIS on this port
        changeOrigin: true,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, '') // The local API has a slightly different path
      }
    }
  }
});
```

I'm successfully calling my API from the Vue app, but I get this error in the command line where I'm running the vite server:

```
5:15:14 PM [vite] http proxy error:
Error: self signed certificate
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1530:34) 
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:526:28)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:944:8)       
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:725:12)
```

I already tried to [add the basic ssl package](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72998216/4320665), and I don't particularly want to install the other NPM package that is in the top voted answer. Why does the vite server complain about a self signed certificate when I'm trying to call another API on my local machine? What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

you could try `secure: false`

```js
  server: {
    https: true,
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'https://localhost:44326', // The API is running locally via IIS on this port
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, '') // The local API has a slightly different path
      }
    }
  }
```

the set of full options is available at https://github.com/http-party/node-http-proxy#options

> #### Options
>
> `httpProxy.createProxyServer` supports the following options:
>
> - **target**: url string to be parsed with the url module
> - **forward**: url string to be parsed with the url module
> - **agent**: object to be passed to http(s).request (see Node's [https agent](http://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_class_https_agent) and [http agent](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_agent) objects)
> - **ssl**: object to be passed to https.createServer()
> - **ws**: true/false, if you want to proxy websockets
> - **xfwd**: true/false, adds x-forward headers
> - **secure**: true/false, if you want to verify the SSL Certs
> - **toProxy**: true/false, passes the absolute URL as the `path` (useful for proxying to proxies)
> - **prependPath**: true/false, Default: true - specify whether you want to prepend the target's path to the proxy path
> - **ignorePath**: true/false, Default: false - specify whether you want to ignore the proxy path of the incoming request (note: you will have to append / manually if required).
> - **localAddress**: Local interface string to bind for outgoing connections
> - **changeOrigin**: true/false, Default: false - changes the origin of the host header to the target URL
> - **preserveHeaderKeyCase**: true/false, Default: false - specify whether you want to keep letter case of response header key
> - **auth**: Basic authentication i.e. 'user:password' to compute an Authorization header.
> - **hostRewrite**: rewrites the location hostname on (201/301/302/307/308) redirects.
> - **autoRewrite**: rewrites the location host/port on (201/301/302/307/308) redirects based on requested host/port. Default: false.
> - **protocolRewrite**: rewrites the location protocol on (201/301/302/307/308) redirects to 'http' or 'https'. Default: null.
> - **cookieDomainRewrite**: rewrites domain of `set-cookie` headers. Possible values:
>
>   - `false` (default): disable cookie rewriting
>   - String: new domain, for example `cookieDomainRewrite: "new.domain"`. To remove the domain, use `cookieDomainRewrite: ""`.
>   - Object: mapping of domains to new domains, use `"*"` to match all domains.
>     For example keep one domain unchanged, rewrite one domain and remove other domains:
>
>     ```
>     cookieDomainRewrite: {
>       "unchanged.domain": "unchanged.domain",
>       "old.domain": "new.domain",
>       "*": ""
>     }
>     ```
> - **cookiePathRewrite**: rewrites path of `set-cookie` headers. Possible values:
>
>   - `false` (default): disable cookie rewriting
>   - String: new path, for example `cookiePathRewrite: "/newPath/"`. To remove the path, use `cookiePathRewrite: ""`. To set path to root use `cookiePathRewrite: "/"`.
>   - Object: mapping of paths to new paths, use `"*"` to match all paths.
>     For example, to keep one path unchanged, rewrite one path and remove other paths:
>
>     ```
>     cookiePathRewrite: {
>       "/unchanged.path/": "/unchanged.path/",
>       "/old.path/": "/new.path/",
>       "*": ""
>     }
>     ```
> - **headers**: object with extra headers to be added to target requests.
> - **proxyTimeout**: timeout (in millis) for outgoing proxy requests
> - **timeout**: timeout (in millis) for incoming requests
> - **followRedirects**: true/false, Default: false - specify whether you want to follow redirects
> - **selfHandleResponse** true/false, if set to true, none of the webOutgoing passes are called and it's your responsibility to appropriately return the response by listening and acting on the `proxyRes` event
> - **buffer**: stream of data to send as the request body.  Maybe you have some middleware that consumes the request stream before proxying it on e.g.  If you read the body of a request into a field called 'req.rawbody' you could restream this field in the buffer option:
>
>   ```
>   'use strict';
>
>   const streamify = require('stream-array');
>   const HttpProxy = require('http-proxy');
>   const proxy = new HttpProxy();
>
>   module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
>
>     proxy.web(req, res, {
>       target: 'http://localhost:4003/',
>       buffer: streamify(req.rawBody)
>     }, next);
>
>   };
>   ```

Comment: Yep that was it. I must've just read right over that in the documentation.

Comment: it's not in the vite documentation. It links to the docs in here though https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-proxy